# Imaginary part of electric susceptibility

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-electrodynamics, complex-numbers

I am reading the book "The Quantum Theory of Light," by Rodney Loudon, and it says on page $24$ that in an environment with electric polarizability $\chi$, the relationship between the frequency and the wavevector becomes\begin{align}\left(\frac{kc}\omega\right)^2=1+\chi.\end{align}The book then goes on to say that $\chi$ takes on complex values of the form $\chi'+\chi''i$. My question is: where can the imaginary part possibly come from? It seems like $k$, $c$ and $\omega$ are all real numbers, so I don't know $\chi$ can be complex without violating the above equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a vacuum, the dispersion relation of electromagnetic waves is $\omega=kc$, and the solutions of the wave equation are the plane waves
$$e^{i(\vec k.\vec r-\omega t)}$$
In non-conducting dielectric media, the dispersion relation is slightly modified: $\omega=kc/n$ where $n=\sqrt{\varepsilon_r}=\sqrt{1+\chi}$ is the refraction index. The solutions of the wave equation are still the plane waves. If the medium is a conductor, Maxwell equations show that the electromagnetic wave will generate a current and that a fraction of its energy will be dissipated by Joule effect. As a consequence, the amplitude of the wave will decay as it will penetrate in the conductor. Plane waves are not solutions of the wave equation anymore. Instead, the solutions are of the form
$$e^{i(\vec k'.\vec r-\omega t)}e^{-z/\delta}$$
when the conductor fills the half-space $z>0$. $\delta$ is the penetration depth of the wave in the conductor. These solutions can be put under the form of a plane wave but with a complex wave vector $\vec k=\vec k'+i\vec k''$ with $\vec k''=-{1\over\delta}\vec u_z$ here. As you can see, the real part of the wave vector is associated with the oscillating part of the wave while the complex part corresponds to the exponential decay of the envelope. One can show that the dispersion relation still holds, but with a complex wave vector $k$ and a complex dielectric susceptibility $\chi=\chi'+i\chi''$.